# How do I implement a spinbox with logarithmic increments in Qt?

Tags: ruby, qt, user-interface, qspinbox

I'm creating a GUI application with Qt (using Ruby and QtBindings, if that matters). I need to make a spinbox with logarithmic increments: that is, each time the user presses the `+` or `-` button, the spinbox value is *multiplied or divided* by a certain amount, rather than increased or decreased. Is this possible with the Qt Spinbox class, and if so, how can I accomplish it?

Comment: If I propose the solution with C ++ or python, would you accept my answer?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to write a custom class drived from QDoubleSpinBox

Comment: @eyllanesc if your solution can be programmed in Ruby (and I don't see why it *couldn't*), I'll accept it.